# Does Kafka support CDC from a source of MariaDB by binlog?

Tags: apache-kafka, mariadb, change-data-capture, binlog

We have a production system running MariaDB, and hope to build an extract-transformation-load (ETL) module with near real-time changed data capture through the database's binary log (binlog) functionality.

For the feasibility, we see an online article, [Streaming Data from MySQL into Apache Kafka](https://sandeepkattepogu.medium.com/streaming-data-from-mysql-into-apache-kafka-db9b5468667e), about the support to MySQL. However, we did not find any online resource about the support to MariaDB.

**Question:**

We hope to get a link to a procedure about Kafka with MariaDB binlog. Or, we also highly appreciate any hints or suggestions.

**Screenshot of the database version:**

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select version();
+-----------------+
| version()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.5.19-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried using Debezium mysql connector? Mariadb should be compatible with mysql

Answer (score 1):

[Maxwell's Daemon](https://maxwells-daemon.io/) is a common transformation tool from MariaDB binary log to Kafka JSON and [regarding MariaDB](https://github.com/zendesk/maxwell/issues/1842), its significantly used.

Its author takes issues seriously and can fix any binary log message aren't parsed right.